# Java Create - Upload Files to Http Server (Tomcat) using HttpClient

Tags: java, tomcat, httpclient

I have a local file `C:\TEMP\296A84G5D98S.pdf` and I want to upload it to a remote HTTP server with username : `adminuser` password: `adminP@ssw0rd` remote server local path Location: `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\FILES` and Server Url is : `http://fileserver:9090/files`

And I have implemented this method, but this is not working and not giving me error. Maybe it not completed or something.

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(
        new AuthScope("fileserver", 9090),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("adminuser", "adminP@ssw0rd"));
//CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
try {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://fileserver:9090/FILES/");
    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(CompleteName));
    HttpEntity httpEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addPart("file", fileBody).build();
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    System.err.println("" + response.getEntity());
    try {
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        if (responseEntity != null) {
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(responseEntity);
    } catch (Exception responseEx) {
        responseEx.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        response.close();
    }
    httpClient.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you share details about the error?

Comment: No error appears and No functionality done ... i have response this : ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8,Content-Length: 963,Chunked: false]} but file not transfered ... i ask if this code not completed or i miss something ...i need Error at least :D

Comment: Use `IOUtils.copy(response.getEntity().getContent(), writer, "UTF-8");` to read the contents of the response and check the server logs too.

Comment: Severe:   ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8,Content-Length: 963,Chunked: false]}
Severe:   java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2002)
 at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1980)
 at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1957)
 at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1907)
 at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1933)
 at dao.DataAccessImpl.transferAttachment(DataAccessImpl.java:535)
 at bean.InbxBean.NewRecordupload(InbxBean.java:1118)

Comment: Set the entity on the HttpPost, as per the code it is not set, it will send nothing. On a separate note, you could also use 'http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/'

Comment: @Ironluca how i can set it ? ...

Comment: httpPost.setEntity(httpEntity);